# Reference ground for Vgs on the source pin of an N-channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, switching, gate-driving, high-side

[image]

Hey fellas,

So I'm trying to take advantage of n-channel mosfet's inherent low RdsOn, but also want a high-side configuration. I've got the following circuit here and it seems to work in this simulator. But I have a few questions.

1. Upon having Vds(12V) and Vgs(15V in the link) equal, my voltage across my MOSFET shoots way up, indicating that I'd be dropping a ton of current on it and blowing it up. Is this accurate?

In my mind, the 1K resistor on the output gives a reference to ground. The reason I have this is that if I want to maintain signal even if the load (30ohm) is disconnected. The 30 ohm is really a placeholder. The real loads this thing could be driving could be anywhere from 2 ohms to sub-ohm loads.

2. Is this a standard configuration that people use for MOSFETs? I know most people will just say to use a P type here, but I'm stubborn and really want to figure out a way to use an N-channel to avoid heatsinks as much as possible. I've never really seen a configuration like this online, but with so many tutorials out there they never really cover this concept.
3. Does Vgs need to be higher than Vds? I figured they could be the same, as I know mosfets can be used to control high-voltage devices with low signal levels. Is this a limitation of the simulator or am I incorrect?

Edit: The reason this is happening is because my Vgs is being referenced to the output of the SOURCE pin, not directly to ground. My voltage is across my load and my "pull-down" resistor, meaning I'm still at Vd at Vs. therefore Vgs MUST be higher than that to drive the MOSFET properly. If a mod wants to lock this that's fine, I answered my own question. Apologies for writing this whole thing but I can't figure out how to delete my own post.

[Here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDsB0AcYCYCsBTAtJEAGaXYBYA2feSBEgTi0LHwgGZMkR96RU0wwAoAJRARlw%20fAKGws2KfkmIpknEm4AzAXgHkxCDaPraIdbgHcta2Kdqisx0-SyjB28gu4AnW-ZD16hL59lYgdwA5l4%20frrh3r4u7o4RtgRSdiGJDkJ0Mdh8IBIJegmS2jKBRdDMCOXy5dwymHl2opYJPO55JbmS0VIICNah7YGdLAUuJmCQvo3gk8JWNn3mvQ7q3dYmi2G%20E1Ph1nGr4Zv0SUWl62lmXqfcAA5efVd6RTLg8jbPV-GbF5-Opv9rPwdnMZts5AoWLJmJDFNwgA) is the link to my circuit. Any comments and advice are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *my voltage across my MOSFET shoots way up* What voltage? Be specific and write for example: Vds becomes 50 V, Id (draincurrent) is 1 A.  *ton of current* ? Be specific. Note that Falstad cannot always be trusted. I suggest downloading LTSpice and try that. Also search for "high side NMOS circuit" and try to understand how those circuits work.

Comment: *Does Vgs need to be higher than Vds?* Vgs needs to be large so that the MOSFET conducts (low resistance). Why do we want that low resistance? Because with a low resistance, when a large current flows, the voltage drop across drain-source of the MOSFET is ....? choose between: small/large.

Comment: Get yourself a high side driver - especially if you want to switch at 40kHz - your opto circuit won’t fly. The high side driver will use a boost circuit that relies on the mosfet switching on/off to create a higher voltage.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie This would be for an automotive style application, so 12v-14.5v would always be my voltage supply. When I turned the MOSFET on with the gate voltage being the same as supply, I had voltage being dropped across the MOSFET where I was thinking there should be none. This however is because I didn't realize Vgs is referenced to my source pin which when the MOSFET is active, is NOT ground. Essentially I wanted no current to be dropped across the MOSFET, or as little as possible.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I understand that now. I got it in my head that a small resistor could reference Vds to ground but in order to do that, I'd have to do a direct connection which just isn't possible. The low resistance RdsOn was wanted because this is intended to drive high current loads like multiple lights or a DC motor in only a single direction or a solenoid.

Comment: @Kartman Hey Kartman, appreciate the comment. 40Khz is not the intended drive frequency, that was more just for the simulation. The 40Khz is just to observe behavior. No boost converter type circuitry happening here

Comment: The 1k resistor is superfluous so why is it there? The 40kHz is equally confusing. The 20k resistor should be between the gate and source. You’ll probably want more than 3 V on the gate - depends on the mosfet etc.  a level shifter would be preferable to an opto especially in an automotive environment.

Comment: @Kartman the 1k resistor was an attempt by me to make this a High-Side driver that will work even if ground is lost on the load side. I was ideally going to have Vgs be about 10V or so to ensure the MOSFET is operating in full saturation. The 3V was more of a question as to why my gate voltage had to be higher than my Vs, but I figured that out as my Vgs doesn't care about it's difference to ground, only the difference between it and the voltage at the source pin.

Comment: @Kartman I have not used level shifters before, only Op-amps. What makes a level shifter more ideal than an Op-amp here? Considering this WILL be in an automotive environment.

Comment: An opamp would not be a good solution - what prompted you to suggest this? You have a level shift problem, so a level shifter is what you want. If your application is automotive, then use an automotive high side switch as it takes care of many evils for you like load dump and current limit. Where were you going to get 15V for the gate drive?

Comment: @Kartman I could have sworn I said opto coupler. Op amp is NOT what I would use here. The 15v(I would probably just have this be 24v or some arbitrary voltage to drive the gate properly with

Comment: @Kartman damn it. Hit post when going for the next letter. I would use a voltage doubler to get a proper drive voltage